# Using model.remove (statement) in Jena

Tags: java, jena

I am new with Jena and do not have much experience with Java. I am trying to make a program that deletes statements from a model. (I know about the alternative method of doing it using a graph and running SPARUL queries but I want to use a model instead). I have tried using the model.remove(statement) but it seems I am not doing it properly. I have searched for an example of the above method but I could not find one. Can someone please help me where I am doing wrong?  I want to start with deleting one statement. After that I want to delete multiple statements. I am including the code below. Thanks in advance for the help

```
     import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.VCARD;

 public class Test3 extends Object  {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     final String  inputFileName = "vc-db-1.rdf";
     Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

     InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
     if (in == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException ( "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
     }

      model.read(new InputStreamReader(in), "");
     in.close();

     System.out.println( "== Before removal ==" );
     model.write( System.out);

     System.out.println( "\n\n== After removal ==" );



     model.remove( model.createResource( "http://somewhere/JohnSmith" ),
             VCARD.FN, // or ResourceFactory.createProperty( "http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#FN" );
             ResourceFactory.createTypedLiteral( "John Smith" ));
     model.write( System.out);
 }

 }
```

The output is as follows

```
   == Before removal ==
    <rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:vCard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#" > 

.....Other statements
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/JohnSmith/">
        <vCard:N rdf:nodeID="A3"/>
        <vCard:FN>John Smith</vCard:FN>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A3">
        <vCard:Given>John</vCard:Given>
        <vCard:Family>Smith</vCard:Family>
      </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>


    == After removal ==
    <rdf:RDF
        xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
        xmlns:vCard="http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#" > 
...Other Statements
      <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://somewhere/JohnSmith/">
        <vCard:N rdf:nodeID="A3"/>
        <vCard:FN>John Smith</vCard:FN>
      </rdf:Description>
      <rdf:Description rdf:nodeID="A3">
        <vCard:Given>John</vCard:Given>
        <vCard:Family>Smith</vCard:Family>
      </rdf:Description>
    </rdf:RDF>
```

Do I need to somehow 'confirm/commit' changes to the model after deleting statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data that you're showing and the resource that you're creating in the program are different.  In your program, the resource being created is

```
http://somewhere/JohnSmith
```

but in the data, it's

```
http://somewhere/JohnSmith/
```

with a trailing `/`.  Once this is addressed, you can remove the triple, as in the following code:

```java
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.VCARD;

public class RemoveStatementExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String n3content = "" + 
                "@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .\n" +
                "@prefix vCard:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#> .\n" +
                "<http://somewhere/JohnSmith/>\n" +
                "  vCard:FN \"John Smith\" ;\n" +
                "  vCard:N [ vCard:Family \"Smith\" ;\n" +
                "            vCard:Given \"John\"\n" +
                "          ] .\n" +
                "";
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel()
                            .read( new ByteArrayInputStream( n3content.getBytes()), null, "N3" );

        // before removal
        System.out.println( "== before removal ==" );
        model.write( System.out, "N3" );

        // remove the statement.  Note that in your data, "John Smith" is an 
        // *untyped* literal, so we use createLiteral( "John Smith" ) rather than
        // createTypedLiteral( "John Smith" ).
        model.remove( model.createResource( "http://somewhere/JohnSmith/" ),
                      VCARD.FN,
                      model.createLiteral( "John Smith" ));

        System.out.println( "\n\n== after removal ==" );
        model.write( System.out, "N3" );
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
== before removal ==
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix vCard:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#> .

<http://somewhere/JohnSmith/>
      vCard:FN "John Smith" ;
      vCard:N [ vCard:Family "Smith" ;
                vCard:Given "John"
              ] .


== after removal ==
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix vCard:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/vcard-rdf/3.0#> .

<http://somewhere/JohnSmith/>
      vCard:N [ vCard:Family "Smith" ;
                vCard:Given "John"
              ] .
```

Comment: Thanks Joshua, Is there a way by which I can delete statements without creating property or resources? I want to read in an RDF file into a model and then delete specific statements from that (just like using a delete statement in SQL). Thanks.

Comment: @Syed You can use `null` as a wildcard, but you're going to have to provide _some_ way of identifying which statements you want to delete.  How do you know which ones you want to delete.  In the example above, you tried to write The URIs directly into the code, and to fix your example, all you'd have to do is wrap them as `new Resource( "http://somewhere/JohnSmith", … )`.  Which statements do you actually want to delete?

Comment: @Syed I've updated the answer to show the particular call to `remove` that it looks like you would want to use, based on your example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to identify the statement with the resource (John Smith), using the property VCARD.FN and 'null' as a wildcard earlier but I got an error. After making changes to the original program accordingly, the statement is still not removed. Can it be because FN is an anonymous node? I am updating the code and also including the output

Comment: VCARD.FN is not an anonymous node;  it's a Property, and properties in RDF cannot be anonymous.

Comment: @Syed There was a typo in the program, and the resource being created was `http://somewhere/JohnSmith`, but based on the data that you showed, it should have been `http://somewhere/JohnSmith/` with a trailing `/`.  I've updated the answer accordingly.